# Tricky proof of ∃x∃yfxy → ∃y∃xfxy using natural deduction - help appreciated!

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I am trying to figure out how ∃x∃yf xy -> ∃y∃xf xy is supposed to work, using natural deduction.

I know how to use the exist elimination rule, but I usually end up somewhere where I don't know how to continue.

Here's my best guess:

$\qquad\large\begin{array}{lclcr}1:&\{1\}&\exists x\exists y~Rxy&\hspace{20ex}&\mathsf A\\2:&\{2\}&Rab&&\mathsf A\\3:&\{2\}&\exists x~Rxb&&\exists\mathsf E(x/a)~2\\4:&\{\}&Rab\to\exists x~Rxb&&{\to}\mathsf E~2!,3\\5:&\{2\}&\exists x~Rxb&&\exists\mathsf B~3,4\\6:&\{2\}&\exists y\exists x~Rxy&&\exists\mathsf E(y/b)~5\end{array}$

Help would be greatly appreciated, got my exam tomorrow :)

Best regards,
Sam!

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text. Use MathJax.

Comment: You need to specify the details of the system you're using - there's more than one natural deduction system

Comment: You need to revise your Elimination and Introduction rules.  These aren't how they work.

Comment: The general approach is ok: instantiate the $\exists$ twice, then introduce it again twice in the other order. But: from 1) to 2) is two steps: first instantiate $x$, then $y$. You don't need 4) and 5). Finally, strictly speaking, you need to do introduce the top-level $\to$ at the very end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an outline natural deduction proof set out Fitch-style, indenting when new assumptions are made. Can you see where steps of existential quantifier introduction and elimination are being made?

$\exists x\exists yFxy\\
\quad | \quad\exists yFay\\
\quad | \quad | \quad Fab \\
\quad | \quad | \quad \exists xFxb \\
\quad | \quad | \quad \exists y\exists xFxy \\
\quad | \quad \exists y\exists xFxy \\
\exists y\exists xFxy \\
$

If you want more on existential quantifier rules, check out Ch 32 of *An Intro to Formal Logic* downloadable at https://www.logicmatters.net/ifl. This very proof is done on p. 311. If you are using a slightly different proof layout, the principles will be the same.